# How to comply with Sonar's rule "SQL binding mechanisms should be used"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, sonarqube, prepared-statement

How do i change the following query to comply with [SQL Injection](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89) rule

```
select * from table where modified_on < now()- INTERVAL '" + interval + " seconds'
```

I could't change the query for preparing Prepared Statement in Java

```
 select * from table where modified_on < now()- INTERVAL ? seconds
```

Comment: Is `interval` an `int` or other numeric? If yes, you can keep it that way because SQL injections aren't possible then. If it isn't numeric make it one ;-)

Comment: Maybe this helps?: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/436170E1.6000909@opencloud.com

Comment: @Lothar, Got your point. I was curious how would we remove a variable. 
Thank you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the number of seconds as a parameter and multiply it with an interval of 1 second

```
select * 
from table 
where modified_on < now() - (? * INTERVAL '1 second')
```